# the remote server return an error : 500 internal server error context.executequery()

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, credentials

I try to connect to another farm in intense to manipulate an SPList on SharePoint 2007: The following code returns :

> the remote server return an error : 500 Internal server error

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://url/"))
            {
                context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "mdp", "domain");
                Site siteCollection = context.Site;
                context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("nameL");                        
                context.Load(list);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                SPListItem oItem = properties.ListItem;
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client object model `ClientContext` is not supported in SharePoint 2007. Use Soap web services instead, [see examples](http://geekswithblogs.net/mcassell/archive/2007/08/22/Accessing-Sharepoint-Data-through-Web-Services.aspx)

Comment: you mine that I should create a web service to connect to the other farm ,thanks

Comment: I guess you would be fine with out of the box web services. Try accessing SOAP services to connect lists residing in other farm. http://server_name/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Comment: the error munche "Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'xxx' failed. any ideas, thx

Comment: Are you are trying to debug the webservice on the server?

Comment: yes I'm trying to debug it with F11 ,but when is use F5 no error appeared .I don't khnow is that a serious error ,or should i ignore it ? beast regards

Comment: i even configured a running remote debuging but it dosent work .any help?

Comment: Check the account you're using for debugging has access in the remote server? Also check the URL reference to the web service

Comment: the info account seems correct which I could acces to the web page.thanks a lot Mahmood

Answer (score 1):

Client side object model code was introduced in SharePoint 2010. It is not supported in 2007. You will need to use web services or some other service like [SPService](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) to work on the lists